# JSch End of IO Stream Read

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm testing out JSch to send SSH command to a remote server. Here's a snippet of my code

```
try {
    session = new JSch().getSession(username, host);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect(5000);

    channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    channel.setCommand(command);
    ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);
    channel.connect(5000);
...
```

Here's the log

```
INFO: Connecting to 192.168.11.31 port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8 PKIX[13.2.3 FIPS]
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server:
INFO: kex: server:
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-
group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client:
INFO: kex: client:
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
INFO: Disconnecting from 192.168.11.31 port 22
Aug 02, 2023 3:06:50 AM com.test.util.LogUtil error
SEVERE: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
        at com.test.util.SshTestUtil.sendSshCommandsTest(SshTestUtil.java:59)
```

It's "mind bottling" -Step Brothers...no, but seriously, I'm losing my mind. I've even tried specifying kex like below, but same result...

```
session.setConfig("kex", "ecdh-sha2-nistp256");
```

I've played with setting different connect timeouts and none, but same issue. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, thanks to both of @g00se and @Martin Prikryl suggestions. Having ran

```
ssh -v dev@192.168.11.23
```

gave me a result of

```
...
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
...
```

The issue was the server was preferring **sa-sha2-512** host key algorithm, JSch was missing. I could have forced **ssh-rsa**, but I decided to look at a forked version of JSch [github.com/mwiede/jsch](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch), which was suggested, since the original is no longer maintained. This forked version supported the server's preferred host key algorithm. It all works now!